# Is this a good way to handle Exception messages?

Tags: php, exception

I wanted some system where I didn't have to keep looking at the Exception class and copying either status codes or text all at once. I also didn't want to have to keep writing plain English error messages after catching exceptions. This seems to accomplish both, plus allows for easy IDE auto-completion!

Here's some demo code:

```
<?php

class Thrive_URL_Exception extends Thrive_PrettyException
{
    const MISSING_CURL = "The cURL PHP extension must be enabled.";
    const MISSING_URL = "A URL has not been supplied or set.";
    const INVALID_URL = "The URL '%s' is not valid.";
    const BLANK_URL = "The URL '%s' contained no data. It is probably invalid.";
    const CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT = "The connection timed out.";
    const FILE_NOT_FOUND = "404: '%s' could not be found.";
    const NOT_ACCESSIBLE = "%d: '%s' is not currently accessible.";
    const PERMISSION_DENIED = "Permission denied.";
}

class Thrive_URL_Downloader
{
    public function fetch($url)
    {
        // Make sure the URL is valid.
        if (!self::isURLValid($url))
        {
            throw new Thrive_URL_Exception(Thrive_URL_Exception::INVALID_URL, array($url));
        }

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => array($this, 'captureHeader'),
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            )
        );

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if ($data === false || is_null($data) || $data == '')
        {
            throw new Thrive_URL_Exception(Thrive_URL_Exception::BLANK_URL, array($url));
        }

        // TODO: Need to handle HTTP error messages, such as 404 and 502.
        $info = $this->getUrlInfo($ch);

        if ($info->httpCode == 401)
        {
            throw new Thrive_URL_Exception(Thrive_URL_Exception::PERMISSION_DENIED);
        }

        if ($info->httpCode == 404)
        {
            throw new Thrive_URL_Exception(Thrive_URL_Exception::FILE_NOT_FOUND, array($url));
        }

        if (in_array($info->httpCode, array(400, 401, 402, 403, 500, 501, 502, 503)))
        {
            throw new Thrive_URL_Exception(Thrive_URL_Exception::NOT_ACCESSIBLE, array($info->httpCode, $url));
        }

        $urlContent = new Thrive_Model_URLContent;
        $urlContent->url = $url;
        $urlContent->headers = $this->headers;
        $urlContent->info = $info;
        $urlContent->content = $data;

        return $urlContent;
    }
}
```

My question is whether there's an obviously better way to do this sort of thing??

Comment: I'd say this is better suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Are they the place to get design pattern help?

Comment: What's Stackoverflow good for then?

Comment: The [FAQ] is always a good place to start for an answer to that question.

Comment: Is there a way to migrate questions? Do I just copy over there and delete here?

Comment: You can flag it and ask for it to be migrated. Use the 'other' reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO it's not best solution.

Your exception class is breaking [*Single Responsibility Principle* (SRP)<sup>­*Wikipedia*</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), because you are using same exception class for different kind of errors. What I'll do is:

Create single exception class for different kind of error:

```
 InvalidUrlException
 PermissionDeniedException
 FileNotFoundException (probalny this exception exists in core php)
```

Then you can use excetion without passing any messages. The message is private part of class.

For larger application this solution is better IMHO.

Comment: +1 I had never thought of that...

Comment: Are that really different kind of errors? I can spot a lot of Thrive_URL_fetch, one Invalid Argument and one Runtime exception. But not more. Take care. And btw. the HTTP error classes are not well represented.

Comment: For me yes, I see these groups of errors: URL, CURL, IO and Permissions. So I will implement at least 4 exception class in this case (of course when using OOP)